# access VBA list box

Tags: vba, ms-access, listbox

I have an access database and I want to make a report based on items selected from a list box,
I wrote following codes for that purpose, can anybody help me and tell me what's wrong with my codes?
Thanks for your help

```
Dim arr() As Variant, item As Variant, strRowSource As String, s As String

With Me.lstOptions

    ReDim arr(.ItemsSelected.Count - 1)
    
    For Each item In .ItemsSelected
        arr(item - 1) = .ItemData(item)
    Next

End With
s = Join(arr, ",")

strRowSource  = "Select cityName from tblMain Where cityName In (" & s & ")"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As cityName is likely a string, you need to put the items into (single) quotes.
Try

```
s = "'" & Join(arr, "','") & "'"
```

**Update** I thought your code to create the intermediate array is working and your problem was just because of the missing quotes. Your loop is using a `for-each`-loop with `item` as index-variable. Item *will not* contain 1, 2, 3 but an index to the selected item and therefore is not valid as index to your array (use the debugger to confirm and understand).

You could introduce an array-index variable:

```
Dim arrIndex as long
For Each item In .ItemsSelected
    arr(arrIndex) = .ItemData(item)
    arrIndex = arrIndex + 1
Next
s = "'" & Join(arr, "','") & "'"
```

Or you could fill `s` directly, without the intermediate array:

```
Dim s As String
For Each item In .ItemsSelected
    s = s & IIf(s="", "", "','") & .ItemData(item)
Next
s = "'" & s & "'"
```

(Disclaimer: I don't have MS-Access available and therefore the code is untested).

Comment: But how about my array. It shows error(9) subscript out of range

Comment: @GourgeGourginian  See my update